# A Commutation of α and β spins of the electron

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

A simple question. Do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ spins commute? In other words, can we say that $\alpha\beta =\beta\alpha$ ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia Pauli Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Commutation_relations)

The Pauli matrices obey the following commutation relations:

$${\displaystyle [\sigma _{a},\sigma _{b}]=2i\varepsilon _{abc}\,\sigma _{c}\,,}$$

and anticommutation relations:

$${\displaystyle \{\sigma _{a},\sigma _{b}\}=2\delta _{ab}\,I.}$$

where the structure constant $\epsilon_{abc} $ is the Levi-Civita symbol, Einstein summation notation is used, $\delta_{ab}$ is the Kronecker delta, and $I$ is the 2 × 2 identity matrix.

For example,

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\left[\sigma _{1},\sigma _{2}\right]&=2i\sigma _{3}\,\\\left[\sigma _{2},\sigma _{3}\right]&=2i\sigma _{1}\,\\\left[\sigma _{3},\sigma _{1}\right]&=2i\sigma _{2}\,\\\left[\sigma _{1},\sigma _{1}\right]&=0\,\\\left\{\sigma _{1},\sigma _{1}\right\}&=2I\,\\\left\{\sigma _{1},\sigma _{2}\right\}&=0\,.\\\end{aligned}}}$$

You should test these  yourself, and reading the above page might also help.

Comment: what is the relation between α  and β with the Pauli matrices?

Comment: Commutators involve operators